# Counting number of copies of a given tree T in a graph G. Looking for a randomised algorithm which is an FPRAS

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, trees, randomized-algorithms, markov-chains

I'm looking for a randomised algorithm (specifically an epsilon-delta approximation) which takes as input a graph G, a subgraph T (which is a tree), and outputs an approximation to the total number of copies of T within G.

If we are given a colouring of G I think it's a little easier but I don't have any concrete results yet.

I was also thinking this can be done using a random walk Markov chain but I'm not sure how to incorporate this.

Ideally the algorithm should be an FPRAS (fully polynomial approximation scheme).

I am extremely grateful for any possible tips/advice. Thank you for reading.

Comment: If $T$ is a path of length $n$ (where $n$ is the number of vertices), you are asking for an algorithm that approximates the number of Eulerian paths in a graph. It is not known whether the number of Eulerian *circuits* can be approximated efficiently, and the situation is likely very similar in the case of Eulerian paths.